# I have made a Project Management Web Application in Asp.net MVC?But now I want to Make the Installer for this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have made a Project Management Web Application in Asp.net MVC?But now I want to Make the Installer for this?

I have to Create one SuperUser While Installation?

Any article how we can Made our Installers or add our steps to Ready Made Installers?

Comment: Your articles are very helpful Seriously